# Count FROM Another column MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my db :

1.groups

```
|------------|------------|------------|
|GroupId     |GroupName   |GroupDesc   |
|------------|------------|------------|
|3           |Group 3     |3rd Group   |
|5           |Group 5     |5th Group   |
|7           |Group 7     |7th Group   |
|9           |Group 9     |9th Group   |
|------------|------------|------------|
```

2.groupdetail

```
|------------|--------------|-----------------|
|GroupId     |MemberUsername|GroupConfirmation|
|------------|--------------|-----------------|
|3           |User001       |Pending          |
|3           |User002       |Joined           |
|3           |User003       |Joined           |
|3           |User004       |Joined           |
|5           |User001       |Joined           |
|5           |User004       |Joined           |
|7           |User004       |Joined           |
|------------|--------------|-----------------|
```

I would like to able to show GroupId, GroupName, GroupDesc and TotalMember (From total member of each group he joined) from the selected MemberUsername and his GroupConfirmation is Joined

I've successfully select GroupId, GroupName, GroupDesc Using:

```
SELECT a.GroupId, GroupName, GroupDesc
FROM groups a, groupdetail b
WHERE a.GroupId =b.GroupId
AND b.MemberUsername = 'user004'
AND b.GroupConfirmation = 'Joined'
```

But I've no idea how I could count the total member of each group, I've tried to use 
    COUNT(b.MemberUsername) but the result just show a single row,

This is the example of result set that I want to get (From User004)

```
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|
|GroupId     |GroupName    |GroupDesc   |TotalMember |
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|
|3           |Group 3      |3rd Group   |4           |
|5           |Group 5      |5th Group   |2           |
|7           |Group 7      |7th Group   |1           |
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|
```

Can anyone help out me here?

thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `group by` and `count`:

```
SELECT g.GroupId, g.GroupName, g.GroupDesc, COUNT(*)
FROM groups g JOIN
     groupdetail gd
     ON g.GroupId = gd.GroupId
GROUP BY g.GroupId, g.GroupName, g.GroupDesc;
```

The `WHERE` clause is superfluous if you want to count all the members.  If you want the total of the groups where the user joined, then add the following `having` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(gd.MemberUsername = 'user004' AND gd.GroupConfirmation = 'Joined') > 0
```

This will filter the groups by only the ones that have `'user004'`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) could be of help.

Comment: I tried this, SELECT a.GroupId, GroupName, GroupDesc, COUNT(b.MemberUsername) as TotalMember FROM groups a, groupdetail b WHERE a.GroupId=b.GroupId AND MemberUsername = 'User004' AND GroupConfirmation = 'Joined' GROUP BY b.GroupId ORDER BY b.GroupId, But all TotalMember columns has 1 value

Comment: Looking at the data you provided, I would guess that's accurate. Notice that you have `MemberUsername = 'User004'` in your query, which means that a count of 1 user named User004 in each group is right

Comment: Yes, you are right, Gordon told me to use having instead of where clause, thank you